# Highchart Stacked Column chart doesn't Consider width after 25 X-Axis Points

Tags: angular, highcharts

With 26 points
[image: With 26 points]

With 25 points
[image: With 25 points]

The below code works fine till we have 25 points on X-Axis the moment 26th Point is added point width is ignored and bar are not displayed properly.

```
this.options = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          events: {
            load: function() {          
              var chart = this,
                xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
                visibleColumns = 5;          
              xAxis.setExtremes(pointStart, pointStart + pointInterval * visibleColumns);          
            },
            selection: this.onSelection,
            click: this.onUnselectByClick,
          },
          type: this.getChartType(this.chartConfig.chartType),
          height: this.height,
          width:2000              
        },           
        yAxis: {
          //maxPadding: 0.5,
          softMax: 100,
          title: {
            text: this.chartConfig.labelY,
          },
          gridLineWidth: 1
          /*min: this.getYAxisMinValue(),
          max: this.getYAxisMaxValue()*/
        },
         xAxis: {
          gridLineWidth: 0,
          categories: chartData.categories,
          min: 0,              
          scrollbar: {
              enabled: true
          },
        },
```

I have used Highchart and HighChart Stocks for Scrollbar

Comment: Hi @Akshay Bhalla, Have you used `boost` module? Also, which constructor type have you used? In case of `stockChart, please try to disable data grouping: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.column.dataGrouping. If this won't help, please reproduce the problem in some online code editor, you can use pure JS and start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek , Yes I have used boost module and my data grouping is disabled.

Comment: Please check the caveats of using the boost module: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module#caveats - try to disable boosting and check if the problem still occurs.

Comment: @ppotaczek, Thanks after disabling boost it is working fine